# mutt colorizing piped messages

Tags: pipe, less, mutt

Viewing messages in mutt are colorized, but piping them through the less pager removes colorization.  How do I preserve message colorization?

I've tried: `| less -R`

but colorization is stripped prior to less input.

Comment: `less` or the pipe probably didn't remove your coloring. It's possible the matt program is detecting where its output is connected to and when it's not a color terminal, it disables color formatting. You need to find the option that overrides this behavior.

Comment: @billc.cn: Yes, that is my point, though I should have clarified it better.  I'd like to know if there's a mutt option for output without disabling color ANSI sequences (before I hack through the source code to investigate).